# Incremental ID using SASS

Tags: sass

I've only just started using SASS so i am noobie. So i am pondering..

I have:

```
#menu0 a{
 Some css
}

#menu1 a{
 Some css
}

#menu2 a{
 Some css
}
```

Now currently i have set the id as a variable (i think), using:

```
$listId: menu + 1;

##{$listId} a{
  width: $listLength;
  background: url('nav-bg.png') no-repeat (-$listLength) * 1 0;
}
```

Now i understand all this is really doing is sticking a 1 on the end of the `menu` ID, but i can't figure it out in my head is i can set an incremental increase in the number it's placing after the ID?

It's not necessary to what i am doing, i am just trying to learn.

Comment: The docs are full of common coding patterns, you should read them:  http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#id11

Comment: Thanks, i found this after i posted, very useful indeed

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the incremental thing right. But i see you're using it to do sprites.

Please consider using [Compass Sprites](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/) instead, it's much simplier.

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked really well, for anyone who might want something like this.

```
 @for $i from 0 through 8 {
        ##{$listId}#{$i} a{
          width: $listLength;
          background: url('/ecc-ac-uk/_img/nav-bg.png') no-repeat ( -$listLength * $i ) 0;
        }
    }
```